# Can multiple requests to IIS occur on the same thread at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

Can two requests to IIS run on the same thread at the same time (i.e., interleaving instructions)? If so, how could this affect a lock that tries to limit access to a shared resource?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, they would run, but both wouldn't be able to lock the same resource at the same time:

Similar question here:
[What happens when two threads ATTEMPT to lock the same resource at the exact same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702794/what-happens-when-two-threads-attempt-to-lock-the-same-resource-at-the-exact-sam)

In this situation, you'd really want to make use of the async keyword and have one await the other.

Comment: I'm more interested in if IIS allows this situation to occur, in which case I'd assume a lock would be granted for both requests.

Comment: In that case, here's a decent explanation of how threads in IIS work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910159/how-are-iis7-threads-assigned